# control the browser that runs on the server for the help of the API in php

Tags: php, browser

Is there any browser on the server debian, which has features of the standard browsers ( firefox, chrome ) . I intend to be able to control it using PHP (like cURL) but with full support for javascript and flash.
After the command must execute all scripts javascript and flash.
Super would be if there was a possibility to perform click on the button with the implementation of the javascript function.

Is something similar has already been created ?

Comment: They have firefox & chrome on linux. Not sure how you'd control them via php though.

Comment: Not specifically Firefox or Chrome, but what about using a headless browser like Phantomjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [**Selenium**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) browser extension, it's a browser automation kit. It supports FireFox, Chrome, Safari and other browsers, it has API support for PHP and will run on Linux. Seems like everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such thing.

Though you could write your own client using javascript in an actual browser.

You may want to check https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Using javascript you can load a page and do anything you want with javascript.

You could install firefox on your debian, add this module and a custom script, and launch it using PHP.